# Hide server when sending email from mail php function

Tags: php

All,
I have the following code:

```
$to = $friend_email[$x];
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "This is a message";
$from = $your_email;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

When the email sends (I'm using Godaddy's hosting service) it says From correctly but then in gmail it says via pxnlhgxxx.prod.xhx3.secureserver.net. Is there anyway to hide the via part or make it say something like website.com? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) docs, you use the optional 5th parameter for the function and pass in the name of the server you'd like to masquerade as:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f sender@website.com");
```

Comment: Google will still show the "via" message in this situation. You have to DKIM sign.

Comment: Your proposed solution won't stop Gmail from showing the 'via' text. DKIM signing will. That GoDaddy shared hosting won't let you do this is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting off godaddy then something like that will happen. You can use your own SMTP server, or use Google free SMTP Server (logging in with your gmail account). Host Gator does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent Google from showing the 'via' notice by [DKIM signing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) your outgoing mail to prove that you genuinely control the domain you're sending e-mail on behalf of.

Answer (score 0):

Its all up to the configuration of the smtp server.